# vagrant 1.8.1 doesn't seem to install ansible when it's specified in ansible_local

Tags: vagrant, ansible

My provisioner is like this:

```
config.vm.provision :ansible_local do |ansible|
  ansible.playbook = '/home/deploy/sosd/local/ansible/sosd.yml'
  ansible.install = true
end
```

But on `vagrant up` it seems like it doesn't install:

```
==> default: Running provisioner: ansible_local...
    default: Installing Ansible...
The Ansible software could not be found! Please verify
that Ansible is correctly installed on your guest system.

If you haven't installed Ansible yet, please install Ansible
on your Vagrant basebox, or enable the automated setup with the
`install` option of this provisioner. Please check
https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/ansible_local.html
for more information.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah this is an issue with vagrant 1.8.1 and ansible 2.x, it installs just fine but can't be detected. https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/6868